# Problema al abrir un enlace dentro de un setInterval?

Tags: javascript

No entiendo por qué intentar abrir un enlace `window.open()` no funciona después del segundo intervalo.

En el ejemplo que muestro a continuación, el enlace se abre correctamente sin ningún problema debido al primer intervalo.

```
var c=1;

var op='';

var i = setInterval(function(){
   if(c==1){
     op = window.open(link);
   }
   c++;
},2000);
```

Sin embargo, si lo intento en el segundo intervalo como se muestra a continuación, simplemente no se ejecuta el `window.open()`

```
var c=1;

var op='';

var i = setInterval(function(){
   if(c==2){
     op = window.open(link);
   }
   c++;
},2000);
```

¿Por qué sucede esto y cómo podría resolverlo?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes solucionarlo incrementando la variable `c`

```js
var c = 1;

var op = '';

var i = setInterval(function() {
  c++;
  if (c == 2) {
    op = window.open(link);
  }

  if (c == 3) {
    op = window.open(link);
  }
  c++;
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que el contador **c** solamente toca el punto una sola vez

if(c==1) o if(c==2)

solo se va tocar una vez porque el contador vale 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 en cada ciclo y nunca mas el contador c vuelve a valer 1 o 2, es por eso que se ejecuta una sola vez

si lo que quieres es que se abra el link en cada valor par deberias usar el operador %

```js
var c=1;

var link = '';

var op='';

var i = setInterval(function(){
  if(c%2==0){
    op = window.open(link);
  }
  c++;
},2000);
```

Comment: ... El problema no es que lo toque solo una vez, el problema es que nunca lo toca si es de un valor superior a 1 en la condicion.